# Running a signed midlet on the emulator produces a SecurityException

Tags: java-me, emulation, securityexception, jar-signing, verisign

I have a signed midlet (VeriSign Class 3), which runs perfectly in several Nokia devices.

When I try to run it on the JME SDK 3.0 emulator it produces a `java.lang.SecurityException: Application not authorized to access the restricted API.`

It has all the permission it needs, otherwise wouldn't work on the devices.
It worked perfectly without the signing, but it's a pain in the neck to click an unclick everytime I compile, depending if I'm running the midlet on the device or on the emulator.

And well, I had to install the **VeriSign CA Class 3** certificate on the emulator, in order to recognize the signature. I don't know if the problem is about this certificate, but without it the emulator wouldn't even start the application cause the CA was unknown.

Has anybody some experience with signatures and this JME SDK emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a newer version of the emulator (Java Wirelesss Tollkit 2.5.2)